# Combinatorics - repetition of randomly generated words

Tags: combinatorics

Consider randomly generated three letter "words" printed on paper. The letters cannot be repeated. a) At least how many of these "words" must be printed to ensure having at least 7 identical "words" on the list? b) At least how many identical "words" are printed if there are 124801 "words" on the list?  I know the total number of possible words without repetiton of letters is 26 * 25 * 24 = 15600. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Suppose you print each of the 15,600 words six times ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you will need knowledge of Pigeonhole principal for solving this question. Refer to wikipedia or any other site and study pigeonhole principal.

Comment: for pigeonhole principal (https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPrZ2moIXPAhWKo48KHdKkCLUQFggpMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPigeonhole_principle&usg=AFQjCNHI592YiNZaKdmr68qq3WZXBWjL2w&bvm=bv.132479545,d.c2I) or(https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPrZ2moIXPAhWKo48KHdKkCLUQFghrMAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.tutorvista.com%2Fdiscrete-math%2Fpigenhole-principle.html&usg=AFQjCNFqY4uMcKnvUt3720j5BS1A3QFSQA)